# Creating a round robin tournament - Create new array with unique elements from second array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Given an array of matchups in a round robin tournament like:

```
pairs = [[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 3], [2, 4], [3, 4]]
```

I want to return a gameweek schedule like this:

```
arr = 
[
  [[1,2], [3, 4]],  // first round:  1 vs 2, 3 vs 4
  [[1,3], [2, 4]],  // second round: 1 vs 3, 2 vs 4
  [[1,4], [2, 3]]   // third round:  1 vs 4, 2 vs 3
]
```

I have the below so far, but getting a problem of "Cannot read property '0' of undefined".

```js
n = number of teams
pairs = array of all potential matchups
arr = final array

for (var i = 0; i < (n-1); i++){
    for (var j = 0; j < pairs.length; j++){
      if (!arr[i][j].includes(pairs[j][0]) && !arr[i][j].includes(pairs[j][1])){
      arr[i][j] = pairs[j];
      pairs.splice(j,1);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47063668/5157454), or this [repository](https://github.com/clux/roundrobin/blob/master/robin.js) might help you.